# Django - Reusing views in different templates

Tags: python, django, django-views

It's probably a stupid question but its really late here and my brain died after my 6th coffee.

I'm building (or trying to) a simple blogging application that would display an article index on the homepage - aka. recent articles - and on the main blog page. To do so I've managed to scribble out a following view:

```
def index(request):
'''Article index'''
archive_dates = Article.objects.datetimes('date_publish','month', order='DESC')
categories = Category.objects.all()

page = request.GET.get('page')
article_queryset = Article.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(article_queryset, 5)

try:
    articles = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    #If page requested is not an integer, return first page.
    articles = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    #If page requested is out of range, deliver last page of results.
    articles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(
    request,
    'blog/article/index.html',
{
    'articles': articles,
    'archive_dates': archive_dates,
    'categories': categories
}
)
```

However to display the index within two different URLs I've copied the code changing only few variables, ie. name and template to render.

1. What could I do to render this view within both URLs yet not duplicate it in my views.py?
2. Am I right in thinking that I'd have to have 3 views, a main one and two sub ones that would import the code from the main one?
3. Or should I be using a custom template tag instead?

**EDIT**

As requested, adding urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.contrib import admin
from settings import MEDIA_ROOT
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from blog.views import *
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
#Blog URLs
    url('^$', home_index, name='blog-preview'),
    url('^blog/archive/(?P<year>[\d]+)/(?P<month>[\d]+)/$', date_archive, name='blog-date-archive'),
    url('^blog/archive/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', category_archive, name='blog-category-archive'),
    url('^blog/categories/', category_list, name='blog-category-list' ),
    url('^blog/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', single, name='blog-article-single'),
    url('^blog/$', index, name='blog-article-index'),
    url(r'^contact/', include("contact_form.urls", namespace="contact_form")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: You should be able to just add a line to your urls.py. Can you edit your post to include yours please?

Comment: Added my urls.py, thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple: map two urls in your conf to the view like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'first_expression', index, name='first'),
                       url(r'second_expression', index, name='second'),
                       )
```

Also, a little advise on your code: try to avoid wildcard imports. They are dangerous...
Insead use:

```
from package import MyClass, my_function, my_etc
```

Comment: That did the trick thank you!
However, is there a way to make the view render different templates depending on the url?

Comment: Have the template_name be a parameter on the view method and pass it in the url pattern similar to how name is used in Alvaro's example.